# Issues in selenium chromedriver headless browser to scrape data from website

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I am using the latest chromedriver 2.45. I am currently building a program which scrape stocks data from a website. I have a list of around 3000 stocks to scrape, so I used multithreading to speed up my work. My program seems to work fine if I turn off the headless browser, but when I turn headless browser to true(with the aim to speed up the script), sometimes the thread will get stuck when running the following line:

```
 browser.get(url)
```

For each stock, prior running the above script, the following script will run:

```
options = Options()    
chrome_prefs = {}
options.experimental_options["prefs"] = chrome_prefs
chrome_prefs["profile.default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
chrome_prefs["profile.managed_default_content_settings"] = {"images": 2}
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument("–no-sandbox")
options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument('--disable-useAutomationExtension')
options.Proxy = None 
options.add_argument("–disable-dev-shm-usage")    
options.add_argument('blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false')
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
browser.minimize_window()
```

The sad thing is when it get stuck in the line, it does not raise any exception. I believe that the thread is trying to access the url but the site does not load so it just keep waiting and waiting? Could that be the case? How to stop the problem? Or maybe a way out is to make a timer for `browser.get(url)`, let say for 10 seconds, if it does not get any data, it will refresh the link again and continue on the script?

Is there also any ways or settings that I can speed up the script? And is it possible to make the program run in the background when I execute the script as it keep popping up (although it minimize itself a second later but the chromedriver is still on the front..)

Thank you for your time!